# Add additional queries to url by link

Tags: php

I have a site that uses query strings to retrieve the data like so:

```
<div id="menu-sort-dropdown" class="search-filter-item">
    <p><?php echo $query_sort_title; ?></p>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="/teachings/">Newest</a></li>
        <li><a href="?sort=SORT_DATE_LIT_ASC">Oldest</a></li>
        <li><a href="?sort=SORT_NAME_ASC">Alphabetically</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div id="menu-category-dropdown" class="search-filter-item">
    <p><?php echo $query_category_title; ?></p>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="/teachings/">All</a></li>
        <li><a href="?category=Coaching">Coaching</a></li>
        <li><a href="?category=Conversation">Conversation</a></li>
        <li><a href="?category=Craft">Craft</a></li>
        <li><a href="?category=Creativity">Creativity</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

It works great getting the data like:

```
teachings/?sort=SORT_NAME_ASC
```

or

```
teachings/?category=Creativity
```

but I can do both like:

```
teachings/?category=Creativity&sort=SORT_NAME_ASC
```

I can't wrap my head around how to add that. If I just append the strip it will become a mess.

Answer (score 0):

The following code doesn't 'duplicate' the values in the url if you keep clicking the `category` or `sort`. It's made to copy/paste and run.

```
// to check the values
echo '<pre>';
print_r($_GET);
echo '</pre>';

echo '<hr>';

function foo($type, $value){
    $args = $_GET;
    $args[$type] = $value; // prevent duplication
    return http_build_query($args); // returns new query string
}

?>
<a href="?<?php echo foo('sort', 'SORT_DATE_LIT_ASC'); ?>">SORT_DATE_LIT_ASC</a>
<br>

<a href="?<?php echo foo('sort', 'SORT_NAME_ASC'); ?>">SORT_NAME_ASC</a>
<br>


<a href="?<?php echo foo('category', 'Coaching'); ?>">Coaching</a>
<br>
<a href="?<?php echo foo('category', 'Conversation'); ?>">Conversation</a>
```

---

You can also have a code to remove any of those. Add it right after the previous code (also copy/paste). Take a look:

```
<?php
function bar($type){
    $args = $_GET;
    unset($args[$type]);
    return http_build_query($args); // returns new query string
}
?>

<hr>
<a href="?<?php echo bar('sort'); ?>">Remove SORT</a>
<br>
<a href="?<?php echo bar('category'); ?>">Remove CATEGORY</a>
```

Comment: You might want to change the function names xD

Answer (score 0):

As for now your dropdown element do a simple action - go to provided url. If you want to select a few values then your elements should store selected value instead of open url. You can do this with for example this JS code

```
var menus = [];
function addElement(type, element) {
    menus[type] = element;
}
```

The type above is number index of your menu type. For example `0` can be for sort and `1` for category - this is for ensure that you can select only one value from menu type. Now you can replace your code with something like this

```
<div id="menu-sort-dropdown" class="search-filter-item">
    <p><?php echo $query_sort_title; ?></p>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="/teachings/">Newest</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript: addElement(0, 'sort=SORT_DATE_LIT_ASC');">Oldest</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript: addElement(0, 'sort=SORT_NAME_ASC');">Alphabetically</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div id="menu-category-dropdown" class="search-filter-item">
    <p><?php echo $query_category_title; ?></p>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="/teachings/">All</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript: addElement(1, 'category=Coaching');">Coaching</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript: addElement(1, 'category=Conversation');">Conversation</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript: addElement(1, 'category=Craft');">Craft</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript: addElement(1, 'category=Creativity');">Creativity</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

To go to the prepared URL you need to add another element like for example a button (or something else with calling `openUrl` function after mouse click)

```
<input type="button" onclick="openUrl('?')" value="Go to URL">
```

And the JS code for `openUrl` function

```
function openUrl(prefix) {
    var url = prefix + menus.join('&');
    document.location.href = url;
}
```